# Issues Updating Class Instance Variables in C#

Tags: c#

In the code below, `systemUsers` is a binding list and `usernames`, `firstNames` and `lastNames` are arrays.

I'm trying to add new users to the binding list `systemUsers` through a loop. After they have been added, I then attempt to update their instance variables such as first name and last name.

However, when I do this, they do not change - they take on a value of `null`. Why is this?

```
public static void CreateUsers() 
{
    // loop over the num. of users
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfUsers; i++)
    {
        // create new user
        systemUsers.Add(new User(usernames[i]));

        // get class instance
        currentUser = systemUsers[i];

       // set class properties
        currentUser.FirstName = firstNames[i];
        currentUser.LastName = lastNames[i];
    }
}
```

`User()` is a constructor which takes the parameter 'username' i.e. `User(string username)`.

Comment: You modify the attributes of the instance in currentUser which isn't the one you added before.

Comment: When you do this:  systemUsers.Add(new User(usernames[i])); the new user instance can't be referenced. As the answers below show, you need to store the new instance in some object, then use the properties of that object to hold the data values. Also, ensure that there is data in the source arrays.

Comment: I've added a few more comments. systemUsers is empty before entering the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below. You need to set the currentUser variable in your loop and then set their FirstName and LastName properties. Right now, you are not setting currentUser anywhere in your code. It is not correct to use a variable without declaring and setting it to some value.

Also, make sure that the arrays of `firstNames` and `lastNames` are appropriately populated and do not contain null values. For example, `firstNames[1]` should not be null if number of users is 2 or more users.

```
public static void CreateUsers() 
{
    //make sure currentUser variable is declared outside the loop
    //or inside the loop at start of the loop body 
    User currentUser = null;

   //make sure your systemUsers binding list is not null
    if(systemUsers == null) {
        systemUsers = new BindingList<User>();
    }

    // loop over the num. of users
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfUsers; i++)
    {
        // create new user
        currentUser = new User(usernames[i]);
        currentUser.FirstName = firstNames[i];
        currentUser.LastName = lastNames[i];

       //add the User object to your list
        systemUsers.Add(currentUser);

    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to put the scope of currentuser outside the loop.

Comment: You are right. It can be put inside the loop too to make it clear that its only used within the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the values of those properties at the same time you instantiate the `User` class. Whatever `currentUser` is referencing, it's *not* the `User` class your instantiating in your example.

```
public static void CreateUsers() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfUsers; i++)
    {
        systemUsers.Add(new User(usernames[i]) { FirstName = firstNames[i], LastName = lastNames[i] });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Will either an AddRange or a direct Initialisation using a Select like :

```
systemUsers = Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfUsers)
                        .Select(i => new User { 
                            FirstName = firstNames[i],
                            // others properties
                        })
                        .ToList()
```